# forEach retrieve index and make Get API call SpringBoot .jsp

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have an issue I'm trying to solve. I want to be able to call an API using the GET method.  I would like to click on someone's "NAME" and after clicking the link execute a GET API call defined via controller. i.e. /test/{test.id}

This is the current table result:

```
NAME  | USERNAME  
--------------------
JOHN. | JOHN345     
AMY.  | AMY6789.    
MARY. | MARY5678.
```

I have the following code in place:

```
<table class="table table=bordered">
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Username</th>
  </tr>


<c:forEach items=${list} var="test" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <form:form id="id" action="/test/${test.id} method=get modelAttributes="test">
    <td><button id ="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="submit">{$test.name}</button></td>
  </tr>
</form:form>
   <td>${test.username}</td>
```

The problem with this is that it gives me all the responses for all the test.ids for each person due to the forEach loop.  I need to have the forEach in place to ensure I have all the test.ids created.

Is there a solution to retrieve only the test.id for that named clicked and then make the GET method call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do this with this viewing engine. But the basic idea is that instead of dynamically creating many different forms, you want to make the form a wrapper, and then inside that form you want to dynamically introduce each item. When the item is clicked, it should trigger the form `action` which should be set as a function that takes in a parameter, and that parameter should be the `item.id`